# obtain the lowest administrative level of several countries

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the lowest administrative boundaries for several countries. 
So far I can download my data at a country level for my countries without problem.

```
world <- c("IOT", "BEN", "TGO")
ac <- list()
for ( i in 1:lenght(world)){
ac[[i]] <- getData("GADM", country=world[i], level=0)
}
world_boundaries <- do.call("bind",ac)
```

Problem none of the countries have the same level of administative boundaries, so each time I tried to change the level to have a lower level, I get an error saying : cannot open URL. I was thinking a creating a loop, that try every administritive level but I couldn't figure it out.

```
ac <- list()
levl <- C("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
for ( i in 1:lenght(world)){
ac[[i]] <- getData("GADM", country=world[i], level=levl)
}
world_boundaries <- do.call("bind",ac)
```

So I a little stuck, I don't know how to resolve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggested way forward using tryCatch. I think this solution could be tidied a bit, but it's a starting point. Basically, for each country, start trying to download the boundary at the highest admin level. If there is a warning or error, skip to the next level. When there is a "success" the tryCatch will finish with the flag still set to TRUE, and the next country will start.

```
library(raster)

world <- c("ITO", "BEN", "TGO")
ac <- list()
levl <- c(0:5)

for ( i in 1:length(world)){
  j <- length(levl)
  while (j >= 0) {
  FLAG <- TRUE
  ac[[i]] <- tryCatch(getData("GADM", country=world[i], level=levl[j]), 
                      warning = function(w) {j <<- j-1
                      FLAG <<- FALSE},
                      error = function(e) {j <<- j-1
                      FLAG <<- FALSE})
  if (!FLAG) next
  if (FLAG) break
  }
}

world_boundaries <- do.call("bind",ac)
```